# Поиск в листе с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, плагин, search

Написал небольшой код для поиска с помощью инпута. В нужном мне списке
все работает.

Как выдать результат, если совпадений не найдено?

```
<div class="search-container">
        <button class="search-choice">Tag</button>
        <button class="search-btn"></button>
        <div class="result-container">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="input" placeholder="Enter tag">
        <ul class="search-list">
            <li>Tag</li>
            <li>Dog</li>
            <li>Cat</li>
            <li>Owl</li>
            <li>Dragon</li>
            <li>Bear</li>
            <li>Lettering</li>
            <li>Bird</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
        return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
            .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
    $('.input').on('keyup', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('.search-list li:contains("'+val+'")').show();
        $('.search-list li:not(:contains("'+val+'"))').slideUp();
    });
```

Comment: а какой вы хотите выдать результат, если не найдено? и где?

Comment: Поправил пост, в блоке result-container, к примеру No results match...

Comment: проверьте что `length>0` - если true - нашлось, нет - нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом, за что спасибо пользователю Grundy, в функцию добавил следующий раздел:

```
if (li.length == 0 ) {
        $('.no-result').slideDown();
        $('.no-result').text('No results match for '+val+'...');
    } else {
        $('.no-result').slideUp();
        $('.no-result').val('');
    }
```